# Can I still travel from Malaysia to Pakistan if my passport number on my Pakistan Origin Card does not match my new passport number?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, international-travel, pakistan

My and my daughter's Malaysian passports are expiring soon, therefore we are travelling to Malaysia to get them renewed.

We have valid Pakistan Origin Cards, which have our current passport numbers. Once we have new passports issued, our passport numbers would be changed and they will not match our POC's passport numbers.

I want to know, can I attach the old passports to the new ones to travel from Malaysia to Pakistan? I might not be traveling with my daughter, therefore I am worried she might have a  problem while travelling to Pakistan, because she is only 12 years and 6 months old.

Please let me know if someone has experienced a situation as above. Thanks.

---

Yes, we both are Malaysian citizen and staying in Pakistan on POC status. I personally believe that travelling back to Pakistan on the same POCs should not be a problem with different passport numbers, as I will attach the old passports to the new ones.

Comment: So to clarify, you are both Malaysian citizens, but you are living in Pakistan using your POC status?

Comment: A cursory web search indicates that you should be able to do a "Modify POC" application entirely online to update your POC's linked passport number, but I have no idea how long this would take to go through.